# SQL database file not getting updated in my github repository

Tags: python, sql, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot hosting in heroku by connecting a github repo
so i have a command which updates the sql database with the author ID
when i was testing in my PC it was updating but after adding the files and new codes in github the sql file isnt getting updates these are codes

````
@event.command()
async def participate(ctx):
 player = ctx.author
 conn = sqlite3.connect('list.sql')
 c = conn.cursor()
 wala = discord.Embed(title='It Seems Goshujin-sama You Have Already Participated In The Giveaway', description='**Good Luck**', color=0xcf24ff)
 gg = c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM list WHERE ID = {player.id}")
if c.fetchone() is not None:
  await ctx.send('Goshujin-sama You Have Already Participated In The Giveaway')
 else:
  c.execute(f"INSERT INTO list VALUES({player.id})")
  conn.commit()
  await ctx.send(embed=wala)```
````

Comment: Are you sure the database file isn't being ignored? Did you commit the changes and push to the remote? This is likely a git question and not a sql question.

Comment: i have added conn.commit() and what is push? can you pls explain

Comment: When you `commit` something it still doesn't do anything remotely it only saves it to your computer with a `commit` message, while in order for it to be saved remotely you need to `push` it using for example `git push`.

Comment: `conn.commit` relates solely to committing the changes to your SQLite DB. It does not have anything to do with a commit in git, which is what my fellow commenters are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you pushed your files to the git? After commit you have to `push` it with `git push`.
2. Are you sure that the database file isn't mentioned in the gitignore file?